# How to access store in second component in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a single component `App.js` where I trying to save state using `redux`. In index.js where I set store for only `<App />` component.

**index.js**

```
let store = createStore(scoreReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

I have this method in `App.js` to map state to props which is available inside `App.js`.

**App.js**

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { score: state.score, status: state.status };
}
```

Everything is well so far, now I am not sure how to access `{ this.props.score}` in another component ?

What changes I need to do in `index.js` and second component if I want to access `{this.props.score}` in another component ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you are using Provider any component that is children of the Provider Higher Order Component can access the store properties though the use of `connect` function.

So you can add the following in any component that is a child of Provider and access the score prop

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { score: state.score, status: state.status };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

However if this other component is a direct child of `App` component then you can also pass the `score prop` as a `prop` to this component from App like

```
<MyComponent score={this.props.score}/>
```

Comment: Can you suggest how to add multiple child of the `Provider` ?

Comment: simply render the component inside the provider component <Provider store={store}><App /><MyComponent/></Provider>,

Comment: Can we access store like `context.store` ? I am getting   `Line 94:  'context' is not defined  no-undef`  `let store = context.store;`

Comment: Not sure, as to how you are using it. But certainly the above method is the way to go

Comment: Congrats, this answer is better than every tutorial and official documentation I've read on react-redux. Including the quick start, which is utterly useless.

Answer (score 6):

`Provider` component sets the context for all its children, providing the store in it. when you use the High Order Component(HOC) `connect` you can wrap any component and access the store through the provided `mapStateToProps` and `mapStateToProps` no matter how nested they are. You can also access the store using context `context.store` but this is not recommended. Using map functions and `connect`, similar to what you have with your `App` component, is the best approach.

Comment: I tried like `render() {
    let store = context.store;` but I am getting an error `Line 94: 'context' is not defined no-undef`

Comment: in your compoent you need to declare contextTypes and if you are using class based components would be this.context

Comment: `let store = this.context.store; console.log(store);` I am getting undefined on console

Comment: did you declare the contextTypes? look at this thread https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/193#issuecomment-158827093