# Container Component cannot find Store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm running into this error: `Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Filters)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Filters)".`

The root of the app looks like so:

```
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Root from './Root';
import configureStore from './store/configure-store';

const props = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(document.getElementById('initial-json').innerHTML));
const reduxProps = { filters: props.filters };
const store = configureStore(reduxProps);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer>
      <Root {...props} />
    </AppContainer>
  </Provider>,
  reactRoot
);
```

**Root Component**

```
export default Root extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="someClass">
        <Filters />
        <Body />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And `Filters` is being hooked into Redux like so:

**Filters**

```
class Filters extends Component {} ...

const mapStateToProps = (props) => {
  return props;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Filters);
// have also tried: connect()(Filters);
```

At first, I thought this might be just an error in how the component was being connected to the Redux store, however I've tried this on a few different components nested inside of `Root` including `Root` itself. I have also tried wrapping only `Filters` in the `Provider` but this introduces the problem where RHL reloads the store.

Finally, I'm beginning to suspect this has something to do with the way the store is being configured. So I'm looking through `configure-store`:

**configure-store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import rootSaga from '../sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const enhancer = compose(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, logger));

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancer);
  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

  if (module.hot) {
    /* eslint-disable */
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () =>
      store.replaceReducer(require('../reducers').default)
    );
  }

  return store;
}
```

My question thus far: Is there something amiss with the way I'm configuring the store, or is there something else I'm not seeing here? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

The redux store should be accessible from the root component via `this.context.store`. When logged from the root component, `this.context` returns an empty object...

Screenshot of `store` prior to being passed to the Provider.

[image]

Comment: can you show `webpack.config.js` , `.babelrc` ?

Comment: Don't see anything weird. Maybe try adding a `console.log(store)` after `const store = configureStore(props);`, and in `configure-store.js`? Might be a problem with the import statements.

Comment: Added a screenshot of store. Appears as I expect.

Comment: Strange. Only other thing I can think of is that you have an extra `<Provider>` somewhere on the path to `Filters`, since somewhere along the way the store in the context seems to get lost. To debug, you could try moving `Filters` or some connected component up the tree. It should work if you put it immediately under `<Provider store={store}>`.

Comment: @Oblosys Yeah, I gave this a shot. No dice. Same error even if I move the Provider to only wrap `Filters`. I am completely stumped.

Comment: Hmm, that's too bad. Can't really do much more from here. If you manage to move `Filters` up to `Provider` (not the other way round) and cut out the rest, maybe you can create a toy example in a https://stackblitz.com or some repo, and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @Oblosys I've tried that as well. I might be closer to answer though... 
Apparently the root component nested inside of `Provider` should be able to access the redux store through `this.context`. When I log `this.context` from the root component, it appears as an empty object.
See Dayan's comment on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617808/how-to-access-store-in-second-component-in-react-redux

Answer (score 2):

Why are you invoking render with the jsx passed to it? Within a React component we should define our render method. Something like

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="someClass">
            <Filters />
            <Body />
        </div>
    )
}
```

This allows us to make use of the components this.props and this.state and derive how we generate content based on those values.

Be careful not to get confused with reactDom.render.

Comment: Good call, sorry I was copying and pasting. That is not the issue.

Comment: Can you show us more of the file with Provider in? Seems a bit odd that you are passing something called props into configureStore, instead of an initialState object as your configure-store file suggests. I think we need a little more code if possible @Jose

Comment: `const props` is parsing some JSON and feeding it into configureStore.
Prior to that it was being passed straight into Root like so: `<Root {...props} />`. Will update momentarily.

Comment: Can you copy the entire files instead of just snippets from them? That way we can check your import statements and other maybe relevant code

Comment: I added the imports. There's some code I cannot add for privacy reasons and also some of these files are massive in size.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being something strange. I downgraded the react, react-dom and react-redux packages to several versions prior and got rid of the error entirely. After upgrading the packages to the latest versions to reproduce the bug, I am unable to.

Comment: Did you have git repo where you can go back to the commit when you posted the question? There could be something that was wrong that

Answer (score 1):

Should be working but seems there is something that cause the side effect.

Have you tried to changing places of AppContainer and Provider, it might be HMR that lose the context.

```
  <AppContainer>
    <Provider store={store}>
      ....
    </Provider>
  </AppContainer>
```

Another desperate thing to try is to move these 2:

```
 const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
 const enhancer = compose(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, logger));
```

within configureStore like:

```
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
     const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
     const enhancer = compose(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, logger));
     const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancer);
     ....
}
```