# How to access redux store from action creator?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm looking at trying to chain actions together.  In my current issue, when the SET_CURRENT_USER action occurs, I'd like it to modify the state (set the current user) and then fire off a bunch of other side-effect tasks (go fetch data, rebuild the UI, etc).   My first thought was "well, I'll set a listener on the store"... which resulted in this previous question: [How to access 'store' in react redux? (or how to chain actions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411136/how-to-access-store-in-react-redux-or-how-to-chain-actions/)  There, I was basically that setting listeners is an anti-pattern.

The solution suggested was to 'dispatch' multiple actions chained together.  I didn't follow how to do that (my "mapDispatchToProps" is based on the redux tutorials and looks nothing like the suggested mapDispatchToProps) so I did some additional googling about how to chain side-effect actions together and got to this page: https://goshakkk.name/redux-side-effect-approaches/

Trying the first example, I went to my action creator file, which looks like this:

(actionCreators.js)

```
export function setCurrentUser(username) {
    return { type: SET_CURRENT_USER, payload: username }
}

export function actionTwo(username) {
    return { type: ACTION_TWO, payload: username }
}

export function actionThree(username) {
    return { type: ACTION_THREE, payload: username }
}
```

and I tried to change the 'setCurrentUser' action creator to something resembling what was in the demo but without the async parts for simplicity - just looking to see if the actions fire:

```
export function setCurrentUser(username) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch( { type: SET_CURRENT_USER, payload: username } );
        dispatch( { type: ACTION_TWO, payload: username } );
        dispatch( { type: ACTION_THREE, payload: username } );
    }
}
```

In my app, my mapDispatchToProps looks like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    setCurrentUser: setCurrentUser,
}
```

and I call this in the switchUser handler, like this: `this.props.setCurrentUser(this.state.newUsername);`

... and I get an error saying that actions must be plain objects.

How can I chain actions together?

Perhaps a deeper issue is that I don't know how to access the store in order to be able to call store.dispatch.  (which was my previous question noted above)

Comment: Are you using thunk as your middleware?

Comment: I am not using any middleware (though will likely add Thunk to do async)

Comment: I think you need redux thunk to dispatch multiple actions

Comment: @lowcrawler. You'll need thunk in order to enhance your action creators. the reason  why you're getting the "must be plain objects" error is because your action creator is returning a function(), not an object. Thunk allows you to return functions in your action creators and with it, the code you wrote should work.

Comment: So the demo's are assuming thunk is added.

@yourfavoritedev - write your comment as an answer and I'll mark it correct (assuming it works... which I'll implement now)

Comment: @lowcrawler done. Let me know if you have any updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need thunk in order to enhance your action creators. the reason why you're getting the "must be plain objects" error is because your action creator is returning a function(), not an object. Thunk allows you to return functions in your action creators and with it, the code you wrote should work.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

const store = createStore(combineReducers({
     data1: reducer1,
     data2: reducer2
}), {}, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

Hope that works.

Comment: worth noting that with the redux devtools, I ended up having to use compose as well in the createStore process

Answer (score 2):

i cannot leave a comment so a question: why dont you just set mapState and pass the state as an argument to dispatched action?

Here are Component stuff

```
class AComponent extends Component{
     ...
     ... onClick={()=>this.props.anAction(this.props.state)}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { state: state.YourReducer }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return { anAction: () => dispatch(actions.doAnyStaffWith(state)) }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BeerReviewer)
```

actions file:

```
export function actionThree(state) {
     return { type: ACTION_TYPE, state }
}
```

That's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access your store like this (illustrating with a fetch request):

```
import { someAPICALL } from '../api'

export function setCurrentUser(username) {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        const { yourStateVariable } = getState().YourReducer
            , data = await someAPICall(yourStateVariable)
                           .catch(e => dispatch({ type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: e }))

        if (data) {
          dispatch( { type: SET_CURRENT_USER, payload: username } );
          dispatch( { type: ACTION_TWO, payload: username } );
          dispatch( { type: ACTION_THREE, payload: username } );
        } else {
          dispatch( { type: SOME_OTHER_ACTION, payload: 'whatever state update you like' } )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Redux thunk would be the ideal way to do it but you can still chain actions by returning promises as your payload.(If you do not want to use thunk)

```
export function setCurrentUser(username) {
    return { 
      type: SET_CURRENT_USER, 
      payload: new Promise(resolve => resolve(username))  
    }
} 

export function actionTwo(username) {
    return { 
      type: ACTION_TWO, 
      payload: new Promise(resolve => resolve(username))  
    }
}

export function actionThree(username) {
    return { 
      type: ACTION_THREE, 
      payload: new Promise(resolve => resolve(username))  
    }
}
```

And then you can call all three like:

```
this.props.setCurrentUser(this.state.newUsername)
 .then(newUsername => this.props.actionTwo(newUsername))
 .then(newUsername => this.props.actionThree(newUsername))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you `mapDispatchToProps` function should look like this: `const mapDispatchToProps = {
    setCurrentUser: (data) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(data)),
}`. Regarding accessing store from your action creators, you need to export it from where you declared it(index.js). import it to your actionCreators file and then use it there. It goes as follows: 
in index.js file: `export const store = createStore(...)` and in your actionCreators file: `import { store } from "your index.js file's path"` and you are good to go. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: redux docs seem to suggest using the object form of mapDispatchToProps (https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch)